# WebSocket, decoding data frame (c++)

Tags: c++, websocket, server

I´m working on a websocket server (in c++) using winsock2. Right now, I´m responding the initial handshake from the client (Chrome in my case) and then I´m sending data from the client:

```
socket.send("Hello!");
```

I´m trying to decode the data frame but I´m having a few issues with it. Lets take a look at the code:

```
int GetBit(const char * data, unsigned int idx)
{
    unsigned int arIdx = idx / 4;
    unsigned int biIdx = idx % 4;
    return (data[arIdx] >> biIdx) & 1;
}

void ParseDataFrame(const char * packet)
{
    int FIN  = GetBit(packet, 0);
    unsigned char OPC = 0;
    {
        int opc0 = GetBit(packet, 4);
        int opc1 = GetBit(packet, 5);
        int opc2 = GetBit(packet, 6);
        int opc3 = GetBit(packet, 7);
        OPC |= (opc0 << 0);
        OPC |= (opc1 << 1);
        OPC |= (opc2 << 2);
        OPC |= (opc3 << 3);
    }  
    int MASK = GetBit(packet, 5);
}
```

I´m getting:

```
FIN = 1 
OPC = x6 (can´t be) 
MAKS = 0 (can´t be)
```

I´ve been reading through the WS Protocol and maybe the problem is in my code.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I would like to mention that the connection is properly established as there are no errors in the console (chrome) and the *socket.onopen* event gets called.

Comment: Can you please show us the contents of at least the first 8 items in the `const char * packet`, and then tell us what you expected to see in `OPC` and `MASK`

Comment: MASK should be 1(masked) and OPC x1 (text). The first 8 chars: `-127,-122,-85,-60,-77,-32,-29,-95`. (printing them with `std::cout << (int)packet[i] << std::endl`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data looks OK, the first byte (-127 in dec, or 0x81 or 1000 0001).

When reading with `GetBit` you use 4 bits per byte in stead of 8.

`biIdx` currently starts on the most right bit going to the most left bit. This should be the other way around:

```
int GetBit(const char * data, unsigned int idx)
{
    unsigned int arIdx = idx / 8;
    unsigned int biIdx = idx % 8;
    return (data[arIdx] >> (7 - biIdx)) & 1;
}
```

That should get you the correct bits.

For the `MASK`, you should read bit 8. As specified: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: Yeah that 5 in the MASK is a mistake! Thanks for pointing it out! By use 8bits per byte do you mean that I have to change my GetBit method? (replace the 4 with 8) Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace both `4`'s with `8` in `GetBit`. I forgot `biIdx`, which currently starts on the most right bit going to the most left bit. This should be the other way around. You can do that like so: `unsigned int biIdx = 7 - (idx % 8);`

Comment: Thanks, I also had to reverse the other of the `OPC |=` it was the other way around :)

Comment: I've been thinking for a while why I have to read each byte as 8 bits (instead of 4) is this because the message is encoded as UTF-8? I though that only the text payload was encoded as UTF-8 not the hole frame. I'm missing something?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, for some reason, I had in my mind that `1byte = 4 bits` I think I should go back to computers for dummies :3